# Menu in ASP.NET Webapplication

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-applications, menu, structure

I have following problem:

I have to make a ASP.NET Webapplication with a two-row menu. It should look like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/J7uSY/1/

Each topmenu item should have multiple submenu items which should be shown in the row below after clicking on the topmenu item.

I tried to do it with only one .NET Menu Control but I couldn't find a way to style the menu statically with two rows.

My second idea was to use multiple .NET Menu Controls and hide/show them by codebhind after a click. Unfortunately this wouldn't be good for SEO because the bots cant find the whole menu structure anymore...

My question is now: What is the smartest way to do that? Can you give me some advice or solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use asp.net controls to do that. CSS with javascript is the way to go, i.e. http://www.devinrolsen.com/pure-css-horizontal-menu/

Comment: But these submenu items are shown while hover over the topmenu items. How I rote above, the submenu items have to be shown/hidden after a click on the topmenu item. I think there is no way to show/hide items only by css...

Comment: not only by css. To make it happend u need to write a litle jQuery

Comment: yes, I also thought about that. But could get kinda complicated if the menu is located in the sitemaster.

Comment: @colosso as you can see in my answer, I never said "only by CSS" but "CSS with javascript"...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fast way to implement this look no further and go with [Superfish Menu](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/). I searched a lot to find this and finally found something that works out of the box with any menu structure you may have. Superfish Menu is a jQuery plugin and so you need to include a reference to [jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js) in your page.